# How to test Android an APK as a developer on a specific device that is not available in the SDK and can not be downloaded in SDK

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-testing

I am wondering how I can test my APK on a specific device which I don't own but an end user has problems on.

For example the `Meizo pro 6` phone is not available in the SDK (AVD) so how can I test my apk on such devices?

Answer (score 0):

make signed APK or debug APK and paster these APK to your device's folder and then try to install it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not any solution to this issue...
The best way to test apk is to upload your release apk to Cloud debugging sites ex : firebase testlab and other sites to maybe find your device .